# How can I limit results when the current page is 1?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I want to show 4 results if current page is 1 and show 6 results if current page > 1, the logic I have in my controller:

```php
    public function emfoco()
    {
        if ($paginator->currentPage() == 1) {
            $emfoco = Noticia::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(4,'*','f');
        } else {
            $emfoco = Noticia::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6,'*','f');
        }
        return view('em-foco')->with(['emfoco'=>$emfoco]);;
    }
```

but this doesn't work because I can't access $paginator in controller, there is anyway to do what I want?

Comment: You're looking for [dependency injections](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)

Comment: This will give you a different set of results. If you have 4 for the first page and 6 for the second, the paginator will assume that you had 6 for the 1st and skip two of them for the second.

Comment: I don't know if I'm looking for that @Cid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to do a custom solution:

```
    public function emfoco()
    {
        if (request()->input('f', 1) == 1) {
            $emfocoCount = Noticia::count();
            $emfocoCollection = Noticia::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(4);
            $emfoco = new LengthAwarePaginator($emfocoCollection, $emfocoCount, 6, LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage('f'), [ 'pageName' => 'f' ]);
        } else {
            $emfocoCount = Noticia::count();
            $emfocoCollection = Noticia::orderBy('created_at','desc') 
                  // If this is e.g. page 5 you skip the 4 on page 1 and the 18 on the 3 other previous pages
                  ->skip(4+6*(LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage('f')-2))->take(6);
            $emfoco = new LengthAwarePaginator($emfocoCollection, $emfocoCount, 6, LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage('f'), [ 'pageName' => 'f' ]);
        }
        $emfoco->setPath($request->getPathInfo()); // You might need this too
        return view('em-foco')->with(['emfoco'=>$emfoco]);;
    }
```

Note in both cases the paginator is set to assume 6 results per page despite the fact that there's only 4 in page 1. This is because the number is basically just to decide the total number of pages. This will (I think) result in the correct total number of pages calculated despite the fact that the first one will have 4 results (because that's all that we're passing)

Update: If you have e.g. 6 total results you might get the wrong pages count so to fix that you can pass `$emfocoCount+2` as your total results count to compensate for the fact that the first page has 2 fewer results than it normally would.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```php
public function emfoco()
{
    if (!request()->get('f') || request()->get('f') == 1) {
        $emfoco = Noticia::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(4, null, 'f');
    } else {
        $emfoco = $emfoco->skip(4 + ((request()->get('f') - 2) * 6))->take(6);
        $emfoco = new LengthAwarePaginator($emfoco->get(), Noticia::count(), 6, request()->get('f'));
    }
    return view('em-foco')->with(['emfoco' => $emfoco]);;
}
```

Comment: this skips 2 results in 2nd page