# Convert object to laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I got object from laravel api with default pagination:

The code is:

```php
public function articles(Request $request) {    
     $url = "https://example.com/api/articles/?keyword=".Input::get('keywords');
     $articles = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) ); 
}
```

the result is

```
{#715 ▼
  +"current_page": 1
  +"data": array:10 [▼
    0 => {#635 ▶}
    1 => {#714 ▶}
    2 => {#713 ▶}
    3 => {#716 ▶}
    4 => {#726 ▶}
    5 => {#721 ▶}
    6 => {#725 ▶}
    7 => {#752 ▶}
    8 => {#753 ▶}
    9 => {#754 ▶}
  ]
  +"first_page_url": "https://exmaple.com/api/articles?page=1"
  +"from": 1
  +"last_page": 446
  +"last_page_url": "https://example.com/api/articles?page=446"
  +"next_page_url": "https://example.com/api/articles?page=2"
  +"path": "https://example.com/api/articles"
  +"per_page": 10
  +"prev_page_url": null
  +"to": 10
  +"total": 4452
}
```

Please help me to convert object to Laravel LengthAwarePaginator.

Comment: I answered a question by using a `LengthAwarePaginator` just today [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62529098/487813) maybe it will be helpful. If you want  help with your code you need to share your code and an actual attempt to actually solve the problem yourself.

Comment: ```public function articles(Request $request) {

  $url = "https://saadaapi.com/api/articles/?keyword=".Input::get('keywords');

   $articles = json_decode( file_get_contents($url) );
}```

result is the object on top

Comment: I have edited this question and added that code in your question (something you should do yourself if you have more information that might be relevant). The constructor signature of `LengthAwarePaginator` is [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method___construct). Try to create a new instance by providing the correct pareameters. All the parameters you need are in the response you get.