# Is there any use of unionall in laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel

I am pulling two different data from the same table in the database.I'm merging this data with union but not all results are shown. So I want to use unionAll. Can I use it with Eloquent?

My code:

```
$model = OrderDetail::with('product')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_first'])->startOfYear(), Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_first'])->endOfYear()])->get()->groupBy(['service_id'])
                ->union(OrderDetail::with('product')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_last'])->startOfYear(), Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_last'])->endOfYear()])->get()->groupBy(['service_id']));
```

When I try with unionAll() I get the following error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::unionAll does not exist.
```

Does unionAll() have different uses?

Comment: It is not unionall it is unionAll

Comment: yes, I spelled it wrong. but when I use unionAll() the same error comes up.
I made the arrangements

Comment: PHP does not have case-sensitive function names so it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query uses [`union`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-union) from the collection not the [`union`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#unions) of the query builder. This is because you have a `get()` before the `union`. To get a rather similar (but probably not identical) result to what you need you can do:

```
$model = OrderDetail::with('product')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_first'])->startOfYear(), Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_first'])->endOfYear()])
                ->unionAll(OrderDetail::with('product')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_last'])->startOfYear(), Carbon::createFromDate($request['year_last'])->endOfYear()]))
     ->get()->groupBy(['service_id']);
```

This makes `union` and `unionAll` usable in that part of the query. Sidenote you might have issues with the eager loading, I've not checked if it can happen in a union query.

Comment: yes, this is how I get the result I want. but i can't paginate like this. I get error paginate does not exist.

Comment: `paginate` is to be used instead of `get` but then your grouping will not work. You can always do some manual pagination by creating an instance of `LengthAwarePaginator` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62529098/487813 might be helpful for that) or drop the `groupBy` in favour of a different solution